# HTML Performance Timing

Tags: javascript, html

Sometimes Chrome sets performance.timing.redirectEnd after performance.timing.requestStart or even performance.timing.responseStart.

[image]

Is it expected and allowed behavior of browser ?

https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/timing-overview.png

Comment: What are you trying to determine?

Comment: Maybe it has cached a redirect?

Comment: @Bergi What is cached redirect ?

Comment: @guest271314 I have some timing calculations and in latest Chrome I noticed that I get overlapping timings. My question is whether it is by specification or Chrome bug.

Comment: Can you include your code at the Question for the purpose of reproducing the results that you are referencing?

Comment: @guest271314 Added screenshot from devtools console,

Comment: @NN_ Can you reproduce the result at plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: @guest271314 First, I need to understand how to make a clean reproduction. It feels like cross-origin redirects makes the problem but I am not 100% sure how exactly to reproduce it.
Anyway my primary question is whether it is according to the spec or not.

Comment: How can that be verified without reproducing the case?

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't find in spec that this is allowed, can you point me where this behavior is allowed?
https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/ 
https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the behaviour in order to determine what is actually occurring. You can file an [issue](https://github.com/w3c/navigation-timing/issues) to ask the authors and contributors to the specification if what you are describing is consistent with the specification.

Comment: @guest271314 Ok, I found a simple reproduction. I just have internal IIS server returning 307 and redirection URL. That's all. I don't see how plunkr allows me to do this. Unfortunately I didn't find any website reproducing the issue yet.

Comment: See https://httpbin.org/

Comment: Try this: https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?status_code=307&url=/ 
Open devtools console and write: performance.timing.redirectEnd > performance.timing.requestStart
In Chrome it returns true, in other browsers false.

Comment: @guest271314 Are you able to reproduce?

Comment: @NN_ Did not get notification of comment. Will try

Comment: @NN_ Yes, able to reproduce http://plnkr.co/edit/IEqqlD1nmLs6WmST3EHm?p=preview

Comment: @NN_ Have you filed bug reports for each browser for interop considerations?

Comment: Didn’t do this. Need to check current behavior again.